# Unexpected na error in R

Tags: r, na, princomp

(Happy Easter)

I have been trying to work out a PDDP algorithm in R, and I keep running into a single, small error while using the `princomp` function. Here is the error statement:

```
Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

From some cursory research, this error comes up whenever there are NA or undefined values in the data in the `princomp` function. However, the data I am using (wikipedia's iris data) has no NA's in it. This is the line of code with the `princomp` in it:

```
pr <- princomp(data[iIndexes,], scores = TRUE, na.action = na.exclude)
```

From my research, I was told this the standard `na.action` value (na.omit) is currently bugged, so I was recommended to use na.exclude instead. I was also suggested to include a function as the first parameter, but this did not change the error message either.

Here is where I got that information: [Omit NA and data imputation before doing PCA analysis using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386439/omit-na-and-data-imputation-before-doing-pca-analysis-using-r)

Let me know if you need the rest of the code in context.
Thanks

**Edit**: As requested, here is the output of `dput(data[iIndexes,])`:

```
 structure(c(36L, 19L, 10L, 6L, 32L, 52L, 8L, 28L, 2L, 20L, ...), .Label = 
 c("4.3,3,1.1,0.1", "4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2", "4.4,3,1.3,0.2", "4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2", ...), 
 class = "factor")
```

The ellipses are further sets of data which are similar to the rest, 150 samples each.

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(data[iIndexes,])` to your question.

Comment: I ran the code. It works for me in R 3.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you run the code without the `class = "factor"` parameter the `pr` will return correctly.

This worked for me:

```
a = c(36L, 19L, 10L, 6L, 32L, 52L, 8L, 28L, 2L, 20L)
b = c("stringa", "stringb")

data = structure(a, .Label = b)

pr <- princomp(data, scores = TRUE, na.action = na.exclude)
pr
```

`pr` returns:

```
Call:
princomp(x = data, scores = TRUE, na.action = na.exclude)

Standard deviations:
  Comp.1 
14.95359 

 1  variables and  10 observations.
```

---

**Solution**

Unclass the data:

`tempVar <- unclass(data[iIndexes,])`

and run the code on tempVar

Comment: the `class = "factor"` is an output. I never told it do do that in the first place.

Comment: I think you are passing `data[iIndexes,]` as an object, when you should be passing a data structure.

Comment: Perhaps you could try `tempVar <- unclass(data[iIndexes,])` and run the code on `tempVar`

Comment: I fixed it using the `tempVar` suggestion. I must say R is extremely counter-intuitive as to what counts as data and what does not.

Comment: @Nathan The actual problem is clearly your data import. You have comma separated values, but didn't tell R this when you imported the data.